# Book: alien fleet invades Earth armed with spears and shields

Tags: story-identification, books, alien-invasion

I'm searching for a science fiction book, with the twist that I haven't actually read this book. I have only heard the outline of the plot of it. But I'm fairly certain that it is indeed a book, and not some plot I dreamt up myself.

It goes like this:

- Due to some silly oversight, **humankind has never discovered anti-gravity** and faster-than-light travel, something other species usually discover around their corresponding stone age.
- Somewhere around the modern day, **an alien fleet lands on Earth, armed with spears and shields**, and demand that humans surrender and become their slaves.
- Obviously, **the aliens get steamrolled** by cruise missiles and tanks and electronic communication, which humans were forced to develop due to being stuck on their own planet without knowledge of anti-gravity.
- Humans steal the alien technology and go into space.

Additional info: I read the plot description in English (but that doesn't say much) in an English speaking online forum which is long defunct. I read it somewhere between 2000 and 2005.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the short story "[The Road Not Taken](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48609)" (1985) by Harry Turtledove, first published in the [November 1985 issue](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56994) of *Analog Science Fiction/Science Fact*.  It is a prequel to his earlier story "[Herbig-Haro](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48826)" (as by Eric G. Iverson).  It's well-enough known to have its own [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_Not_Taken_%28short_story%29).  It's been in several different anthologies, but I'm not sure if any are currently in print.

The premise is that somehow anti-gravity is "easy" to discover, but is a technological dead end, so that races that discover anti-gravity end up exploring the stars, focusing their energy outward.  Whereas on Earth, failure to discover anti-gravity lead to the Renaissance and modern technology.  (This is handwaved as the gravity device offering no useful insights into how the world works, whereas investigation of, for example, light, leads to the whole electro-magnetic spectrum, electricity, spectroscopy, x-rays, radio, etc.)

In the story the aliens actually fought with matchlock guns and simple muzzle-loading cannon.  Heat-seeking air-to-air missiles don't work against their ships, since they lack a strong heat source, but radar-guided missiles work, and modern military weapons make short work of the invaders.

The story ends before humans actually go to space, but with the realization on the part of two captured aliens (an infantry captain, and an engineer/navigator) that humanity is now going to be effectively unstoppable.

Comment: It seems to match nearly exactly, as you say. I've marked it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Question: Did the Aliens call the Human machine guns, something like "Stitching Weapons"? I recall a story like this, but THAT weapon description is what stuck out to me.

Comment: @NJohnny No, that's a different story. It was a full-length book, but I do not remember the title or author, just that it was definitely different than "The Road Not Taken".

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will keep looking. ;)

Comment: I, also, thought that the aliens in The Road Not Taken called our marching guns "stitching guns".

Comment: @NomadMaker That's "Pandora's Planet" by Christopher Anvil; details are in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/236899/101407).

Comment: Your last paragraph-remark is taken up in Turtledove's story "Herbig-Haro", published earlier.  "Road Not Taken" is a prequel ("origin story") of how humanity conquered the stars.