# Invading aliens' low tech weapons are no match for Earth's modern weapons

Tags: story-identification, alien-invasion

This is *not* "The Road Not Taken" by Harry Turtledove.

Similar story idea, but I read Turtledove's story before posting this and it's not it.

Probably a short story. (Can't think how it might be stretched to a novel's length.)

In English, written at least 20-30 years ago.

The one I am trying to remember had slightly more advanced aliens.
But their weapons were still primitive compared to Earths weapons. (Still single shot but probably not muzzle loaders.)

I recall the fight not being quite so one-sided. (In Turtledove's story the "ground battle" was over in just a few minutes, most aliens not even getting off a second shot.)

I seem to recall the ground forces having time to report back to their commanders of the battle's progress. (i.e. They had radio communications.)

The ***main*** thing I recall is the aliens describing humans' full auto weapons as "stitching guns" or "stitching weapons." (Because when their troops would be hit by them they would get 4-5-6 holes appearing side by side across the body in a line.)

I seeming to recall the invasion lasted days or weeks before the aliens were defeated. (Maybe because the aliens didn't want to give up thinking the humans "stitching guns" *had* to run out of ammo soon. No way the humans could have that much ammo.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Stitching guns" is a term used by the alien invaders of Earth in Christopher Anvil's "[Pandora's Planet](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55740)" (1956).

The aliens (other than interstellar flight) are roughly equivalent tech to Earth:

> Brak Moffis looked at Horsip and gave a wry smile. "Technologically," said Moffis, "they were very near Centra 0.9, and in some areas higher."

The aliens have fighting a long, costly war against human guerrillas.  At the start of the story they have been fighting on Earth for about 4 months, and have managed to establish several fortified beachheads and largely reduce most organized large-scale opposition.

The aliens' weapons are single-firing multi-shot weapons (like big shotguns) they call "splat guns."

> "let's get back to this stitching-gun. It only shoots one dart at a time. How does that make it better than our splat-gun, that can shoot up to twenty-five darts at a time?"

They call human machine guns "stitching-guns":

> "What’s wrong then?” demanded Horsip.
>
> "The natives’ stitching-gun,” said Moffis dryly.
>
> "The which?” said Horsip.
>
> "Stitching-gun,” said Moffis. "It has a single snout that the darts move into from a traveling belt, like ground-cars on an assembly line. The snout spits them out one at a time and they work ruin on our men."

Comment: Yes that's it. I either read that, or the revised and expanded version "Pandora's Legions" (2002)

Answer (score 5):

This is likely to be *Pandora's Planet* by Christopher Anvil, originally appearing in [*Astounding Science Fiction* in September 1956](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v58n01_1956-09_dtsg0318-LennyS).

It was later reworked into the start of a full-length novel, *Pandora's Legions*.  An excerpt from the novel:

> "What's wrong then?" demanded Horsip.
>
> "The natives' stitching-gun," said Moffis dryly.
>
> "The which?" said Horship.
>
> "Stitching-gun," said Moffis.  "It has a single snout that the darts move into from a traveling belt, like ground-cars on an assembly line.  The snout spits them out one at a time and they work ruin on our men.  If this five-hundred man team you speak of was hit on the road, and just fifty men from it tried to beat the natives, we'd probably lose all fifty."